# Update column using comma-separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server:

**Table1**

```
ID  SkillSetRequired                 SkillDesc
1   100-1,101-1,102-2,103-3          null
2   100-4,105-2                      null
3   100-1,102-2,104-2                null  
4   100-5,102-2                      null   
5   105-1                            null
```

**Table2**

```
ID    SkillName
100   .Net
101   Java
102   JQuery
103   Sql
104   PHP
105   C
```

I need to update the `SkillDesc` column of `Table1` with the SkillNames. For example in first row I need to update skilldesc as `'.Net,Java,Jquery,SQL'`

How can I do this with out using cursors?

I am getting the result in a string from the below query for a single record. But I need to update all the rows.

```
declare @result varchar(max)

SET @result = ''            
SELECT @result = @result + ltrim(rtrim(SkillName)) + ',' from  #Table2 where id in(
                         select SUBSTRING(items, 0 + 1, CHARINDEX('-', items, 1) - 0 - 1)  from split('100-1,101-1,102-2,103-3',','))
                         select @result
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the values like that. Is fixing (i.e. properly normalize it)  your data model an option?

Comment: No... This is an old Table. I wont b able to alter this table becs it is already in use  :(

Comment: is this a one off or continually required problem?

Comment: I need it continually. The records will be added by a scheduled service which i does not have access. I need to update all the records where SkillDesc is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cursor is the best option even though it is taking time to execute.

```
     SELECT ID,SkillSetRequired 
     FROM #Table1
     OPEN @CurSkillUpdate
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM @CurSkillUpdate INTO @id,@skills
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
        SET @result = ''            
        SELECT @result = @result + ltrim(rtrim(SkillName)) + ',' from  #Table2 where id in(
        select SUBSTRING(items, 0 + 1, CHARINDEX('-', items, 1) - 0 - 1)  from split(@skills,','))          
        update #Table1 set SkillDesc=@result where ID=   @id
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM @CurSkillUpdate INTO  @id,@skills
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, How did u insert 100-1,101-1,102-2,103-3  into the table ?

Do the below maping while adding the above.
Use a Case statement like

```
Case 
when @Skillset = '100' THEN @desc = .Net
when @Skillset = '101' THEN @desc = Java
....
END
```

same way for other skill sets.

Then while inserting into the table for every id add the skillset and use the @Desc for the which updates

Comment: The values are added by a job which i does not have access. The table is containing more data and i need to do the update for all the records... It s taking much time when i used cursor

Comment: This would be more work and a pain.. wast of lot of time. But still u have a solution for this. extract the skillset column to the tmp tbale. and join the table-2 with it where u get the desc.  split each column and map the desc with CASE statement and concatenate them with comma. I know it s too confusing.. wel If you take it step by step u can do it..

Answer (score 1):

How did u manage adding 100-1,101-1,102-2,103-3 . This is not the proper way to add...

Comment: Ya... But i cant change that.... the table is old and which hv more data and already in use :(

Comment: only way is to use a temporery table for this. Use the temp table split the , seperated and add corresponding desc for each , by using case statement .. put them all in one one tmp table.. Then using this tmp table add the results to the main tbale based on ID.

Comment: Thanks Ranjitha ... i m trying with temp tables